# The offline, the online and the firebase.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, reload

I have a script which runs functions when the device becames online/offline. 
The firebase.js linked in the head section.

```
<script id="firescript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"> </script>
```

//the code observing navigator status and run the proper function:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  fire();
} else {
  fireoff();
}

//if online:

function fire() {
//will be here a "couldn't find firebase.js" error when offline status 
//changing to online

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
     firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
}
```

I had a "couldn't find firebase.js" error when the html was loaded in offline status and then it became online, the script could'nt find the firebase.js (because the index.html was not reloaded) How to load the firebase.js in this situation without reloading the page? Thank you!

Comment: Note that you are using. a very old version of Firebase SDK, which is currently in V5.0.4, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I've changed it to v5, thanks. It was json parse errors when changed, but I solved it

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no.